# VideoView stops other apps' music in the background

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, android-audiomanager

I have a VideoView without any audio playing every time I start my app. I have noticed that when it starts playing, music playing from other apps in the background pauses. Is there any solution to this? Thank you!

Comment: maybe your `VideoView` get the audio focus (check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html#RequestFocus)). Can you post the code about your `VideoView`?

Comment: @L.Swifter just the typical VideoView code. setOnPreparedListener, videoView.start in onResume(), stuff like that.

Comment: If you remove `videoView.start()` in the `onResume()`, the background playing will not pause, I think.

Comment: @L.Swifter where should I put the videoView.start() then?

Comment: You should call `start` method when you want to start playing video. Does the background playing works properly when you remove `start` in `onResume`? If so , I will post an answer.

Comment: I transferred the start() invocation on onCreated from onResume but the same thing happens. I need to simultaneously play my video without interrupting other apps' background music.

Answer (score 0):

Playing video while background music playing is not recommended:

> To ensure a great user experience, it’s also important that your app manages the audio focus to ensure multiple apps aren’t playing audio at the same time.

You can check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/index.html) for more information.

When you start play video using `VideoView`, you app request the audio focus, this mean the background app which is playing music lose the audio focus. The background app's behavior depends on the code in `AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.OnAudioFocusChangeListener` method. You can not change it.

More information, see [Managing Audio Focus](https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html).